# What units do defense buildings target first?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In trying to develop a good attack strategy, I need to know more about how the defense building AI works.  As of this question there are seven different defensive buildings (cannon, archer tower, mortar, air defense, wizard tower, hidden tesla, crossbow).  The game is pretty clear that some target ground, some air, and some both.  What I am interested in is, given many eligible targets:

- In what order are targets attacked?
- Is it as simple as the first eligible target in range?
- Do targets queue (such that 2nd, 3rd etc will get attacked even if a closer target comes into range after the 1st one dies)?
- Do defensive buildings prioritize targets that are attacking them?

  These kinds of nuances make a big difference when selecting and deploying a raid group, since every unit is precious and you don't have exact control over where they path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand, priority goes to closest eligible target within range (until dead or out of range).

This is why many attack first with Giants to draw in enemy fire, and then use ranged units like Archers or Warriors to take out defenses.

Comment: Hi Justice, welcome to Arqade!  I've done some significant study in this area, and it seems you are right.  Defenses seem to be the troop targeting equivalent of "any".  I have noticed that there is a special note about the Tesla targeting P.E.K.K.A.'s, but since I so rarely seem them it doesn't matter much to me.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Recently, I think I saw a troop getting targeted by a wizard tower, but this troop was attacking a different building, then some archers came on from behind, and started shooting at the wizard tower. Then the tower changed to shoot at the archers even though the other troop was not dead. I'm not 100% sure about this, but it did look like it. After I saw this I have tried to notice how this works, but I have not seen see other examples.